# Displaying a div at a certain time resetting when the month changes

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div/tab set to display after the 1st of Feb of this year.  This works great until the month ends and the div is then hidden again.  I want the div to remain open forever.  The first tab is set to display on the Feb 1st, the second is set to display on the 14th. Here is my code.

```
<style>

.disable-1, .disable-2 {
  display: none;
}

.enabled {
 display: block;
}

</style>

<ul class="tabs">
    <!-- THIS UL CREATES THE TABS == Just add/remove LIs as neeed to create them. Be sure the IDs of the sections match -->
    <li><a href="#PLY-EC-001-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="disable-1"><a href="">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="disable-2"><a href="">Tab 3</a></li>
    <
</ul>

<script>
    // get current date on page load
    var date = new Date();

    // ask for specific date
    if (date.getFullYear() >= 2020 && date.getMonth() >= 1 && date.getDate() >= 1) {
        // get first dom-element with that class 
        var li = document.getElementsByClassName('disable-1'); 

        // if dom-element exists
        if (li.length > 0) {

            // set classname
            li[0].className = 'enabled';
        }           
    }

    if (date.getFullYear() >= 2020 && date.getMonth() >= 1 && date.getDate() >= 14) {
        // get first dom-element with that class 
        var li = document.getElementsByClassName('disable-2'); 

        // if dom-element exists
        if (li.length > 0) {

            // set classname
            li[0].className = 'enabled';
        }           
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for the year, the month and the current date *via logical AND*, just check if the current date is bigger than a specific timestamp (2020-02-01:00:00:00 in your case):

```
var date = new Date();
var refd = new Date(2020,1,1,0,0,0); // <-- Reference date

// compare if now (date) is bigger than reference (refd)
// by comparing the milliseconds since 1970-01-01
if (Number(date) >= Number(refd)) // <-- compare
{
    // ... elided, as before
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's perfect... Thanks you very much :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayDiv()
{
   var d = new Date();
   var strDate =  d.getDate();

   if(strDate == '1')
     document.getElementById('HelloWorld').visible= true;
}
</script>


<form onLoad="displayDiv()" method="GET">
<div id="HelloWorld" style="display:none;"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This shows the `div` on every first day of every month but keeps it hidden for all other days (it's visible on: 2020/01/01, 2020/02/01, 2020/03/01, ... 20XX/0X/01, ...etc. and hidden otherwise). That's not what the OP wanted.